# Using malloc to create a 2d C style array of my class

Tags: objective-c

(Edit: put possible solution at end)

I'm a C/C++ programmer who is learning Objective C to develop iPhone apps. The programs that I will be writing will deal with large 2d arrays of objects. I've read about using NSArray's of NSArray's and have some working code, but I'm trying to understand how to use C style arrays to save overhead and to learn what you can and can't do.

In this fragment MapClass only contains two properties, int x and int y. I have the following code fragment working with a statically defined array of 10x10.

```
MapClass *arr[10][10];

arr[2][3] = [[MapClass alloc] init];
arr[2][3].x = 2;
arr[2][3].y = 3;

NSLog(@"The location is %i %i", arr[2][3].x, arr[2][3].y);
// Output: "The location is 2 3"
```

This is an example of doing it with a one dimensional array and calculating where the cell is based on the X and Y:

```
MapClass **arr = (MapClass**) malloc(10 * 10 * sizeof(MapClass *));

arr[3 * 10 + 2] = [[MapClass alloc] init];
arr[3*10 + 2].x = 2;
arr[3*10 + 2].y = 3;

NSLog(@"The location is %i %i", arr[3*10 + 2].x, arr[3*10 + 2].y);
// Output: "The location is 2 3"
```

**My question is this**: How can I malloc my array as a two dimensional array so that I can use arr[2][3] style notation to access it?

Everything I'm trying is generating various errors such as "Subscript requires the size of [your class], which is not constant in non-fragile ABI".

Can anyone give me a snippit on how to do this? I've been reading and experimenting and can't figure it out. Does my one dimensional array example do anything wrong?

## Answer?

After fooling around with xzgyb's answer, I have the following block working. Anything wrong with it? Thanks!

```
int dimX = 20;
int dimY = 35;

MapClass ***arr = (MapClass***) malloc( dimX * sizeof(MapClass **));
for (int x = 0; x < dimX; ++x)
{
    arr[x] = (MapClass **) malloc( dimY * sizeof(MapClass*));

}

for (int x = 0; x < dimX; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dimY; ++y)
    {
        arr[x][y] = [[MapClass alloc] init];
        arr[x][y].x = x;
        arr[x][y].y = y;

    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < dimX; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dimY; ++y)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i %i is %i %i", x, y, arr[x][y].x, arr[x][y].y);

    }
}

// Cleanup
for (int x = 0; x < dimX; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < dimY; ++y) {
        [arr[x][y] release];
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < dimX; ++x)
{
    free(arr[x]);
}

free(arr);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I'd like to note that you haven't used `malloc` here to begin with.

Comment: Yes, the fragment is statically allocated and works. I want to know how to dynamically allocate it with malloc.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to allocate the array dynamically? C does allow you to have have dynamically-sized static arrays, if that's what you're wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the followed code:

```
MapClass ***arr = (MapClass***) malloc(10 * 10 * sizeof(MapClass *));

for ( int row = 0; row < 10; ++row ) {
    arr[ row ] = (MapClass **)&arr[ row * 10 ];
}

arr[0][1] = [[MapClass alloc] init];
arr[1][2] = [[MapClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: This works when I use any arr[0][x] but as soon as I try arr[1][x] or higher I crash with a bad_access exception. I'm experimenting with it now though, thank you.

Comment: Think I got something working, added it to the first post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tested and it works fine using NSMutableString class and a variety of string methods.
I'd probably recommend using the standard message sending brackets than using the newer dot operator syntax just to simplify to the compiler what you are actually trying to accomplish.

The sizeof(ClassName *) should be the same as sizeof([ClassName class]) (and int* or id for that matter) if I understand your meaning.  The code you posted should not give an error like that as all pointers will be the same size.  Now if you tried something like sizeof(*someInstanceOfAClass) then you're running into some issues because you're attempting to malloc enough memory to fit 10*10*(the actual size of your object) which is not what you're intending to do. (And sounds like what your warning is intended for.)